# load a form action result page into <div> without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, forms, action

I would like to load the result `(add_cart.php?action=add&id=".$item[$i]['id'].")."` of this select form in a div but still passing the variable to the `add_cart.php` page load the `add_cart.php?action=add&id=".$item[$i]['id']."` page into a div without refreshing but having the page do the action.

The code:

```
print("<div id='add_cart'></div>
    <form action='/add_cart.php?action=add&id=".$item[$i]['id']."' method='post'>
        <select name='id' class='select'>
            <option selected='selected' value='".$sku[$s]['id']."'>".$sku[$s]['id']."</option>
            <option value='".$sku[$s]['id']."'>".$sku[$s]['id']."</option>
        </select>
        <input type='submit' class='add_cart' value='".$lang['add_cart']."'>
    </form>
");
```

the add_cart code:

```
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
$id = $_POST['id'];
}else{
$id = $_GET['id'];
}
$id_user = $_GET['id_user'];


    $cart = $_SESSION['cart_order'];
    $action = $_GET['action'];

    switch ($action) {
case 'add':
    if ($cart) {
        $cart .= ','.$id;
    } else {
        $cart = $id;
    }
    break;
case 'delete':
    if ($cart) {
        $items = explode(',',$cart);
        $newcart = '';
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($id != $item) {
                if ($newcart != '') {
                    $newcart .= ','.$item;
                } else {
                    $newcart = $item;
                }
            }
        }
        $cart = $newcart;
    }
    break;
case 'update':
if ($cart) {
    $newcart = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (stristr($key,'qty')) {
            $id = str_replace('qty','',$key);
            $items = ($newcart != '') ? explode(',',$newcart) :        explode(',',$cart);
            $newcart = '';
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($id != $item) {
                    if ($newcart != '') {
                        $newcart .= ','.$item;
                    } else {
                        $newcart = $item;
                    }
                }
            }
            for ($i=1;$i<=$value;$i++) {
                if ($newcart != '') {
                    $newcart .= ','.$id;
                } else {
                    $newcart = $id;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
$cart = $newcart;
break;
```

}

Comment: Please look into using jQuery/AJAX to achieve this.

Comment: any indication, I am very bad with jQuery and been frustrated for a while now ... an example maybe? thanks

Comment: jQuery.load() will probably be the best function for you to use. You can use it like: `$('#DivID').load('Your Script URL');` Where DivID is the ID of the div you wish to load the result in to.

Comment: I must be a complete moron what am I doing wrong, thank you! ' <script src='code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>; <div id='add_cart'></div> <form id='form' action='#' method='post'> <select name='id' class='select'> ... </select> <input type='submit' class='add_cart' value='".$lang['add_cart']."'> </form> <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("form").submit(function(){ alert("Submitted"); $('#add_cart').load('/add_cart.php?action=add&id=".$item[$i]['id']."'); }); }); </script>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search for Ajax. which let you work "without reload the entire page" for achieve this and make your life easier you can relay in some framework (jQuery, Prototype, Mootools, Dojo, Yui) are some of the most popular, my suggestion is to use jQuery because is the most popular and I think is quite easy to use.

Also you can take a look to this tutorial [http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/](http://jsfiddle.net/nQBjW/)

Found just typing `php and ajax tutorial` on google.

http://jsfiddle.net/nQBjW/

HTML

```
<select name='id' class='select'>
    <option value="some value">some value</option>
</select>
<div id='add_cart' style='background:#f60; color:#fff; font-family:arial; max-width:120px; text-align:center; display:block; padding:5px; border-radius:5px; cursor:pointer'>agregar al carro</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var makeAjax = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/", //'/add_cart.php?action=add&id=".$item[$i]['id ']."' replace with you url on your server
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            some: "data"
        }
    }).done(function (resp) {
        alert(resp);
    });
};

$("#add_cart").on("click", function (event) {
    makeAjax();   
});
```

Comment: I must be a complete moron what am I doing wrong, thanks you! ' <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>    <div id='add_cart'></div>
    <form id='form' action='#' method='post'>
        <select name='id' class='select'>
           ...
        </select>
        <input type='submit' class='add_cart' value='".$lang['add_cart']."'>
    </form>
 
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
    alert("Submitted");
 $('#add_cart').load('/add_cart.php?action=add&id=".$item[$i]['id']."');
  });
});
 
<script>
 @MatthewMcGovern
 
</script>'

Comment: @fedex I have edit my answer check it out... you can see a fiddle working

Comment: @fedex if work for you pls mark as answer of at least upvote pls :D

Comment: I updated the fiddle with proper link but it gives error [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nQBjW/3/) suggestions?

Comment: ooops, sorry never used it before, did it on the server too ... but no luck here's the link [link](http://www.doombo.com/cippa2.php)

Comment: need to see your add_cart.php?action=add&id=140 code you should return something in json format, I think you should do the tutorial before to start building you own solution IMHO

Comment: i edited my question with the add_cart.php basic code, thanks for your help

Comment: you are submitting the form because you are using the input type=submit, that is why is not workint you have to use a type=button or something else and NOT submit the form, AJAX doesnt need a form for works. Man I encourage you to take the tutorial I already send to you you need to understand several things before to start working with ajax. I will appreciate if you mark this answer as solver or upvote. Best

Comment: I'll look into it further. Thank you for your help. Best